# Chat on behalf of user in GTalk,yahoo, MSN?

Tags: asp.net, yahoo-api, google-talk, msn, yahoo-messenger

I want to develop application in Asp.net in Which user can send message to me and on behalf of them i need to send chat message to Gtalk,MSN or Yahoo. and also recieve messages for Same.

Please let me know if anyone have idea?

Thanks in Advance..